# Update UITextField periodically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield

I am working on an app where i need to update the text inside `UITextField` after short intervals. I am getting the text to be updated and intervals in a dictionary. I am parsing the dictionary and setting the `UITextField` text then waiting for one second.

```
- (void)startDisplay{
    for (NSDictionary *dictData in [dictTestData valueForKey:@"frames"]) {
        [_txtFieldDisplay setText:[dictData valueForKey:@"frame"]];
        [NSThread sleepUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];
        [_txtFieldDisplay setText:@""];
    }
 }
```

But the `UITextField` is not getting updated regularly. It only shows the final text in the end.Help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text field won't actually update until the current run loop has a chance to complete. There are two problems with your code.

1) You sleep in the main thread - VERY bad.

2) You reset the text before the change has a chance to take effect.

GCD would be a good way to solve this:

```
- (void)startDisplay {
    float delay = 0.0;
    for (NSDictionary *dictData in [dictTestData valueForKey:@"frames"]) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_txtFieldDisplay setText:[dictData valueForKey:@"frame"]];
        });
        delay += 1.0;
    }

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_txtFieldDisplay setText:@""];
    });
 }
```

And as "iMoses" mentioned, another approach could be to use an `NSTimer` but that requires more setup.

Comment: A less resource intensive approach would be to use a repeating timer, and of course setup the data for easy access prior to that.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and pointing out the issues in my code but now the textfield shows complete text as soon as the loop ends. What i am trying to do is to show some text then a pause then again show some text and pause, it goes on till the dictionary is parsed completely.

Comment: @Deepesh OK, I misunderstood. Give me a few minutes to update. It's still the same basic idea.

Comment: @rmaddy: Sure no issues and thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: @Deepesh I updated the answer. I think that is what you want. It will cycle through each string for 1 second and then clear the text at the end.

Comment: @rmaddy: Thank you very much for sparing some time :) it worked perfectly thank you so much.